# Kibana cannot use field of type number in visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using elastic 6.8.
I want to plot the responseTime field against the timestamp that the measurement was taken.

The mapping for the responseTime for the index is:

```
"responseTime": {
    "type": "long",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

In Kibana under the Management tab -> Index Patterns I see the field as Name: responseTime, type: number

In the Discover tab I can find the data that I want to visualize like this:

```
timestamp                       responseTime
October 5th 2019, 16:59:00.868  3
October 5th 2019, 16:59:00.581  6
October 5th 2019, 16:58:59.886  4
```

Under the Visualize tab I choose for Visual Builder and go to Metric, aggregation: average. As field I choose responseTime. Even this is giving me no output. The result is average: 0;
So I still cannot use the field in a visualization.

Why can I not use the field correctly in a visualization? What should I change?

Comment: Please verify that ALL elasticsearch indices behind the kibana index pattern have the same mapping for this field and there are no conflicts in the index pattern. If so, try to refresh the field stats.